# Electrostatics charges problem

Tags: electrostatics, momentum, energy-conservation, charge

Two positively charged particles X and Y are initially far away from each other and at rest. X begins to move towards Y with some initial velocity. The total momentum and energy of the system are $p$ and $E$ respectively. In this problem, can you tell me what happens if both charges are free to move? Is total energy conserved? Why is momentum not conserved??

Comment: If (X) goes directly toward (Y), then over a long period of time this becomes a one dimensional elastic collision.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum is conserved. Momentum is a vector. If the charges start at rest, the total momentum is $0$. If the charges rush toward each other, one is moving left and the other right. The momentum vectors are equal and opposite. They total $0$.